# My Discord music bot stops songs 20 seconds before it is meant to

Tags: javascript, bots, discord

Now i'm not that good at Javascript, i consider myself still a learner as i still make quite a lot of mistakes from time to time (not without being able to fix them shortly after) but i am at a complete loss with this Discord bot that i'm coding, now i know that a decent amount is my code but this one area of my code i believe to possibly be the culprit of my discord bot cutting off the music stream around 20 seconds before the end.

```
function play(guild, song) {
const serverQueue = queue.get(guild.id);

if (!song) {
    serverQueue.voiceChannel.leave();
    return queue.delete(guild.id);
}

const dispatcher = serverQueue.connection.play(ytdl(song.url))
    .on("end", () => {
        const shiffed = serverQueue.songs.shift();
        if (serverQueue.loop === true) {
            serverQueue.songs.push(shiffed);
        };
        play(guild, serverQueue.songs[0]);
    })
    .on("error", error => console.error(error));
dispatcher.setVolume(serverQueue.volume / 100);
```

I am completely at a loss as i am not that good at Javascript i would really appreciate the help!

Edit:
Should mention i seen this post:
**[Discord bot audio end before the song end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59692386/discord-bot-audio-end-before-the-song-end)**
they have the exact same issue as me and they said they were able to fix it but i am not able to do so and i would really appreciate if someone could give me a bit of help on this

Comment: Try changing the "end" event to "finish"

Comment: I did originally have it as "finish" when i encountered the error but i seen a lot of other people using the "end" event instead so i thought i'd give that a try, but neither seem to fix my issue so i'm just gonna keep it at finish

Comment: Maybe this https://github.com/fent/node-ytdl-core/issues/402#issuecomment-457841788

Comment: It says to add "reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 4" if using ffmpeg, do i put this under configurations in the README.txt file?

Comment: If that was the part i was meant to add it didn't help at all