# Discord Music bot - the song i play stopped 10-20 seconds before the end so i added highWaterMark and now the song barely plays at all

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

So basically i had [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62135569/my-discord-music-bot-stops-songs-20-seconds-before-it-is-meant-to) and i got given a "solution" but it didn't work, so i found a fix and that was adding highWaterMark to my code so the stream stays open longer or whatever idk, so this is what my code looks like currently

```
    const dispatcher = serverQueue.connection.play(ytdl(song.url, {
        filter:"audioonly",
        highWaterMark: 1<<25 })
        .on("finish", () => {
            const shiffed = serverQueue.songs.shift();
            if (serverQueue.loop === true) {
                serverQueue.songs.push(shiffed);
            };
            play(guild, serverQueue.songs[0]);
        })
        .on("error", error => console.error(error)));
    dispatcher.setVolume(serverQueue.volume / 100);
```

but now my issue is that the song will play for like 10 seconds then just stop, i have no idea why this just made my issue worse because for everyone i seen that used this solution it worked perfectly.

Comment: I actually have had the same problem for a while now, but only when running my bot ln my Windows 10 computer. When switching to my Linux server, the problem is gone, and I wonder whether it could be OS-related. I'd suggest you to do some testing on a Linux computer or Virtual machine if you can, and if you still don't get an answer in a few days, I might consider placing a bounty on this question since I'm sure it could help a lot of people.

Comment: Best i got is a Chrome OS laptop which i can use linux and have used linux on, i got the bot to work on my laptop but if i am not mistaken i remember having the problem still, i've been at a solution for days some help would really REALLY help me as i barely have any idea what i am doing, i am alright at javascript just not the greatest

Comment: I'll try to run mine on a virtual machine tomorrow. I will tell you if it changes anything, fingers crossed for someone to find an answer by then.

Comment: Did you end up running your bot on your linux virtual machine. Haven't really gotten any further with my issue i still have the problem :/

Answer (score 0):

There recently was an update of ytdl, you should try to run a quick `npm update` on your project.

Also, I've tried [this module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ytdl-core-discord)  and the issue seem to be gone for me. You might also want to make sure that you have both `ffmpeg` and `ffmpeg-static` on your project, I think this may have helped to fix the issue in my case.

Comment: I have already tried to use ytdl-core-discord but it doesn't seem to play well with my code, do i have to use this module side-by-side with regular ytdl-core or something?

Comment: I do have both 

Comment: Have you ever tried to install the recommended modules from the discord.js documentation ?

Comment: I don't know where to find the recommended modules, also i will try and install ytdl-core-discord and also keep ytdl-core, would i need to replace ytdl-core const with ytdl-core-discord or should i have both????

Comment: @DGTBHItzDG you'd need to replace the old with the new discord one

Comment: Yeah i thought so, only reason i asked is when i add the "-discord" part, i run the play command after my bot loads up and i get 
"I could not join the voice channel: Error [VOICE_PLAY_INTERFACE_BAD_TYPE]: Unknown stream type"

Comment: Maybe you're missing some requirements ? Try to run a `npm update` maybe ?

Comment: Would i need to possibly change my code for the play part shown in my original post?

Comment: @DGTBHItzDG I guess not.. you should try

Comment: If not, could it possibly be that i am missing an important module? It says on Discord.js website "With voice support (@discordjs/opus)" and also "(opusscript)" should i add them because i currently don't

Comment: @DGTBHItzDG yes, I'd really recommend you to install them

Comment: How would i add them to const??? Or do i not need to, do they just need to be installed as modules to work?           **Edit**: i added both modules, not sure if they need to be const or not but it still says the same error

Comment: Having them installed should be enough

Comment: Welp, it seems i'm not gonna be able to fix this then. Adding ytdl-core-discord seems to stop my bot from being able to play any songs so idk where to go from there